# Compiler design: Is it worth simplifying an expression?

Tags: compiler-construction, operators, compiler-optimization

I had an idea for a compiler optimisation for expressions:

If I have the following expression `y = x + x + x`
I can simplify it to be `y = 3*x`

However after doing some research I came across this blog [post](https://streamhpc.com/blog/2012-07-16/how-expensive-is-an-operation-on-a-cpu/) about operators costs, stating that:

> The cheapest of the cheapest, in this order:
> addition, subtraction, comparison (1)
> abs (2)
> multiplication (4)

Where the number is a weight cost to each operator.

This being said, is it a common practice to simplify expressions in compilers using common algebraic techniques? According to the blog post, in the example I gave it would only be worth simplifying with a multiplication operator if there is more then 4 addition operators.

Comment: You should keep in mind that 3*x is not necessarily equivalent to x+x+x. Consider the overflow case (if x is integer), for example. Also, cost of multiplication may vary wildly, so I'd rather leave this sort of optimisations until the very microarchitecture-specific instruction scheduling step.

Answer (score 2):

It is useful because e.g. x86 can do **3* efficiently by using lea (`lea eax,[edi+edi*2]`). If **3* cannot be encoded efficiently, the compiler can easily decide in later stages that the **3* should be replaced by two addition operations or a shift and an addition.